# MapFrom not being called for null collection

Tags: automapper

I want to upgrade AutoMapper library in my project from v4.2.1 to the latest that still supports .NET Framework 4.5.2 (which to my knowledge is AutoMapper 7.0.1). I have code like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;

    cfg.CreateMap<ExampleDto, Example>(MemberList.Source)
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemsAAA, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.items.ConvertTo<TypeAAA>()))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemsBBB, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.items.ConvertTo<TypeBBB>()));
});
```

`ExampleDto.items` is a collection that should be split to `Example.ItemsAAA` and `Example.ItemsBBB` based on every item type. `ConvertTo` is an extension method, and it returns an empty collection if input parameter is null. This used to work in AutoMapper 4.2.1, but in 7.0.1 `ConvertTo` is never called for `x.items == null`. How can I make AutoMapper call this mapping even if the `x.items` is null?

Comment: `MapFrom((source, _) => source.items.ConvertTo<TypeAAA>()))`

Comment: @Lucian can't compile that. Maybe it's available in some newer version of AutoMapper, but not in 7.0.1.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing

Comment: That is related to AutoMapper 8.0. I have to use AutoMapper 7.0.1, like I explained in the question.

Comment: If it only were some way to find out what version came before 8.0. Now, that would explain a lot :)